# vs2015 and vc++ external dependencies error on build

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

i am learning vc++ and i make my first application win32 console and just write simple code and i get 20 error from external files automatic included

i change compile as to c++ and not using precompiled headers but stil have errors

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //cout << "hello !" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

how can i fix it ?

[image: my errors]

Edit :

i have win7 and vs2015 perhaps helps

Edit 2:

last picture is for an empty project this one is for a win32 console app

[image: second Image]

Comment: it have not any references and dependencies folder empety but when i build the project the dependencies folder fill and i get these error

Comment: I just tested with Visual Studio 2015 and had no difficulty creating a win32 console application using the `New Project` wizard. The default generation had already created a `.cpp` file which has `#include "stdafx.h"` as the first line since precompiled headers are on by default. The rest of my code is the same as yours.

Comment: i have these error every where in all project types
worst thing is those error are for defualt libraries

Comment: Did you add `#include "stdafx.h"` as the first line of your source file? And create a `stdafx.h` file in the same folder as your `.cpp` file? Although the compiler output should tell you that as the first error in the Output window. Press Alt-2 to see the Output window then compile.

Comment: i use empty project with out headers and any refrence
and wonderfull thing is that when i dont add any code project build without error but when i just add that include i get those error

Comment: If you are not getting the error message about precompiled headers I say time to uninstall then reinstall Visual Studio 2015. Make sure you verify that the c++ compiler is selected for install.

Comment: i think so seems must do that see second edit too

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a project set to use precompiled header. Can you start with an empty project and add source file?

And don't forget to set "Not using precomplied header" in file option

Comment: do you have error when you use precompiled headers?

Comment: no in empty project it has not headers but still in build i have those error
and wonderfull thing is that when i dont add any code project build without error but when i just add that include i get those error

Comment: you open a project now with precomplied headers .. i mean include "stdafx.h"  .. just to check it it works well

Comment: problem with installation then. Check compiler to see it's c++ complier. If everything is Ok, then reinstall.